# Login Redirect to third party service (i.e. Auth0)

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is is possible to configure **admin-on-rest** such that the login page redirects to a third party login service, like [Auth0](https://auth0.com)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be. It will probably imply to have a [custom route](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customroutes) for the callback url. This route should be a connected component which will trigger the appropriate redux actions (`USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I understand it, by defining an `authClient` in my `App` forces a redirect to `/login` if not authorized. Is is possible to redirect to a hosted auth page using a [custom route](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customroutes)?

Comment: No but you can use the component you'll bind to the login route to redirect to Auth0